# Why is there so little data-driven fluid dynamics research?

Tags: soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning, data-analysis, fluid-dynamics

With the insane growth of data science, I notice that there's hardly any data-driven fluid dynamics research out there.  What could explain this phenomenon?

I have heard that fluid dynamicists generally want to do their research based on first principles, i.e. use physics, and not use data-driven methods that might not care for domain knowledge.

Having said that, I'm still somewhat surprised that not more fluid dynamicists have done data-driven work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'data-driven research'?

Comment: @Mattos like a machine learning paper on fluid dynamics

Comment: [Here is an article on maching learning applied to the Kuramoto-Sivashinsky PDE.](https://www.quantamagazine.org/machine-learnings-amazing-ability-to-predict-chaos-20180418/)

Comment: With data-driven methods, you learn nothing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see -- but medical machine learning has really taken off, e.g. using ML for new drug discoveries.  So, I'm wondering why data-driven methods couldn't make a significant contribution to fluid dynamics (my area of interest ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for people doing physics research, especially mathematical analysis, data-driven approaches are basically useless. A deep NN can't really *guarantee* that its output is realistic nor can it *guarantee* that it will generalize to situations never seen in the training data. If one wants to understand the underlying mechanisms, then ML can't really help usually.

I know there are also people in physics-based animation that don't use it either, since for some applications deep NNs are too slow and/or hard to train. Maybe they are less interested in it as well. Either way, this could likely change soon.

On the other hand, there *are* plenty of data-driven fluid dynamics work! For example:

- [Kutz, Deep learning in Fluid Dynamics, 2017](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/deep-learning-in-fluid-dynamics/F2EDDAB89563DE5157FC4B8342AD9C70)
- [Zhang & Duraisamy, Machine Learning Methods for Data-Driven Turbulence Modeling, 2015](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2015-2460)
- [Beck et al, Deep Neural Networks for Data-Driven Turbulence Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.04482)
- [Wiewel et al, Latent-space Physics: Towards Learning the Temporal Evolution of Fluid Flow, 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10123)

Comment: +1 for the references.